# Embeding a secondary HTML file within a webpage

Tags: html, object, iframe, seo, ssi

I still don't feel comfortable repeating HTML for things like menu code, header, footer and most importantly a quick links/news panel on each page.  Also it seems a little inefficient to keep sending the same repeated html for each page.

For the moment I have written a small program which reads these sections from my index.htm and replaces the relevant sections within all other pages in that directory.  However things have started to get considerably more awkward now that I have extra pages like a Message Forum and Image Gallery, both of which require their own index.htm in their respective sub directories.

So the question is should I be using object, iframe or SSI?

Has anyone successfully used the object tag to embed a separate HTML file within a page?  SSI would do the job except that the repeated HTML is still being sent across the web on every page change and different include lines would have to be used on the PHP pages.  What about using IFrames, I know they are not strict XHTML1.0 compliant but I seem to recall rumors that they are going to br supported in HTML5 again, does that make them a good bet for the future?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this problem is by using a scripting language (PHP, Python, ASP) and templates. You can create the basic structure for your site in a master template, then use the scripts to pull in only the content that changes.

For a particularly good example, see [Django's template system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/).

Comment: OK for any Python pages we have but would not work with the PHP based Message Forum.

Comment: There are several PHP-based template languages available: Smarty, Pear's HTML_Template*, etc. You could also upgrade to a full CMS like Drupal or Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

Each of your pages could call a JavaScript function in an external `boilerplate.js` file. That function could add boilerplate elements to the page, using the DOM.

That said, **you might not want to do this, nor use IFrames, for SEO reasons**! (Also, your pages would not fail gracefully if the client disabled JavaScript.)

To me it seems better to have a more search-engine-friendly page and put up with the transmission of duplicate markup. Server Side Includes (or any server-side scripting language) would give these qualities while also making it easy for you to change the boilerplate on all pages at once.